# Sqlalchemy multi-threading

Tags: python, mysql, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I simplified my problem.
So the example tries to insert new records into the database in parallel.

The code works perfectly with processes = 1 but returns the following error when processes is greater than 1.
So the problem is in creating a session or a session pool for each thread running.

> I get this error :
>   OperationalError: (mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError) MySQL >Connection not available.
>   [SQL: INSERT INTO `Var3` (chrom, pos, ref, alt, htz_count, hom_count) >VALUES (%(chrom)s, %(pos)s, %(ref)s, %(alt)s, %(htz_count)s, >%(hom_count)s)]
>   [parameters: [{'pos': 1353203, 'alt': 'G', 'htz_count': '0', 'ref': 'C', >'chrom': 'chr1', 'hom_count': '1'}]]
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Manager
import pandas as pd

from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, MetaData, Integer, String
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


# =============================================================================
# Variant class definition
# =============================================================================

class Variant(object):   
    def __init__(self, chrom,pos,ref,alt, htz_count, hom_count):
        # self.var_id = var_id
        self.chrom = chrom
        self.pos = pos
        self.ref = ref
        self.alt = alt
        self.htz_count = htz_count
        self.hom_count = hom_count


def insertionVariant(df_set):
    session = Session()
    for index, row in df_set.iterrows():
        new_var = Variant(row.chrom, row.pos, row.ref, row.alt, '0','1')
        session.add(new_var)
        session.commit()



# =============================================================================
# Open database connection and create tables if not exist
# Ouverture de la base de donnees, creation de la table si elle n existe pas
# =============================================================================

engine = sa.create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://python:ln17iesaphyv@localhost:3306/variant',
    echo=True, pool_size=10)


session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=True)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)

metadata = MetaData(engine)

variant_table = Table('Var3', metadata,
        Column('var_id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
        Column('chrom', String(40)),
        Column('pos', String(150)),
        Column('ref', String(300)),
        Column('alt', String(300)),
        Column('htz_count', Integer),
        Column('hom_count', Integer)
    )

if not engine.dialect.has_table(engine, 'Var3'):
    print("CREATE VARIANT TABLE ...")
    variant_table.create()
else:
    print("VARIANT TABLE ALREADY EXIST")    


print("MAPPAGE DE LA TABLE ...")
mapper(Variant, variant_table)


# =============================================================================
# Database Update
# Insertion ou mises a jours des donnees
# =============================================================================


data = pd.read_csv('Test.csv', sep='\t')
subdata= data[['CHROM', 'POS','REF','ALT', 'INFO:AF']].copy()
subdata.columns = ['chrom','pos','ref','alt','af']

##Multi-threading processing
manager = Manager()

pool = Pool(processes=5)
#split input dataframe
df_split = np.array_split(subdata,5)
#map each subset to checkVariant function, return list of dataframe tuples
res = pool.map(insertionVariant, df_split)
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here, which makes it a little difficult to get to the root of the issue. I suggest solving a simpler problem. First, ensure you can connect to the database and run a simple query from your multiprocessing code. Second, ensure you can run a simple insert from your multiprocessing code. Then take the lessons learned from the simple solution to your production code.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.

I will try to deal with insertions in multi-threading.
To be more precise, the problem is at the session.query () level in the checkVariant function.